# Hibernate @AttributeOverride which results in setting the property as @Transient

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Apart from this, if it is the right pattern to do it this way, the question is wheter is possible in a Hibernate for a given `@MappedSuperclass` set up the overriden property as a `@Transient` or ignore it in any 'other way'?

Given mapped superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class MappedSuperclassEntity {
    private Integer field;
    public Integer getField() {return field;}
    public void setField(Integer field) {this.field = field;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible. Javadoc of `@AttributeOverride` :

> (Required) The column that is being mapped to the persistent
>   attribute. The mapping type will remain the same as is defined in the
>   embeddable class or mapped superclass.

You can look at one of the three [inheritance strategies for JPA here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) for another design.